# How to redirect http to https in Apache Web Server?

Tags: php, docker, apache, redirect, cakephp

I have a cakephp application running on docker container with apache web server inside it.
My current apache config looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

And if i go to http://localhost or http://localhost:80 on my browser (somehow localhost redirects to localhost:80) it says 400 Bad Request and i should use https instead of http. Okay, so i go to https://localhost:80 and it works fine (note : https://localhost doesn't work, i have to put the port number at the end)

My question is, how do i make http://localhost to show what https://localhost:80 currently shows?

I already tried to change my apache config to this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     Redirect permanent / https://localhost/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

And if i go to http://localhost or http://localhost:80 it's redirected to https://localhost alright, but it doesn't work (unable to connect). If i go to https://localhost:80 or https://localhost:443 it also doesn't work. How should I modify the apache config to make it work on http://localhost? Does my Dockerfile or docker-compose configuration affect this? I tried asking chatGPT all this but the answer it gave me doesn't help.

Comment: https uses 443, not 80.  Technically you *can* listen for TLS connections on 80, but clients won't expect it.  you can't listen on 80 for both HTTPS and HTTP - some protocols allow that typically via STARTTLS , but HTTPS does not work that way.

Comment: how should i change my apache config to then?

Comment: `https://localhost:80` should not work, and why do you care if `https://localhost:443` does? Just use `https://localhost`.